# Issue with the File Upload tool ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a file upload tool in used in a very simple way. It is required to take the file (very small ones around 20-25 KB) and transfer those to a remote server.

Each server has given the access to a particular Username and password to I had to use Impersonation before using the File.SaveAs() function.

```
public void btnUploadFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
                    try
                    {
                        string strUploadDir = GetFileUploadLocation(ddlRole.SelectedItem.Value, fuupload.FileName);
                            objCommon.ImpersonateUser("xxxxxx","xxx", "xxx");
                            fuupload.SaveAs(strUploadDir + "\\" + fuupload.FileName);
                            objCommon.EndImpersonation();
                            divUploadMessage.InnerHtml = "<font color='green'><b>File uploaded successfully.</b></font><br>";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        divUploadMessage.InnerHtml = "<font color='red'><b>Failed to upload. Please try again. Error : " + ex.ToString() + "</b></font><br>";
                    }                
    }
```

Now, the issues I have :

1. In one server when i upload the file the file size reduces to Zero, so basically it becomes an empty file
2. From other server when i use this, i am getting an Unknown username or bad password error, whereas i have checked the user credentials which are fine. Moreover the IIS settings are set to user Windows Authentication.

For what impersonation is used, below is the code.

```
public bool ImpersonateUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
    {
        WindowsIdentity objIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    objIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                    impersonationContext = objIdentity.Impersonate();
                    if (impersonationContext != null)
                    {
                        CloseHandle(token);
                        CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Format the code so it's readable please

Comment: Phillip I am not sure what you meant by formatting the code to make it readable...i can see the code in blocks perfectly fine..